# How and where self object is alloc?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

There are many methods which override functions like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

So the `super` is calling the parent classes function, but where is **self** allocated?

Answer (score 1):

`self` is a pointer to the “current object”, it’s allocated in the usual initialization formula:

```
NSObject *foo = [[NSObject alloc] init];
```

When you call `[NSObject alloc]`, the class creates an object that you later refer to as `self`.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we initialize our class like this with nib:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

or simply **init** the self will be allocated

Answer (score 0):

Basically it is initialized in init function like this:

```
- (id) init
{
  self = [super init];
  return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
```

This is assigning value in self

When you call you class and `alloc` it then it access it's super class `init` method and pass to self.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self)
    {

    }
    return self;
}
```